# Laravel Base table or view not found on server

Tags: php, laravel, server, localhost

My Laravel application is working properly on Localhost, but when I uploaded it on my server it is showing me this error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Comment: Maybe you forgot to run migrations or something?

Comment: Run `php artisan migrate` in your server, database is empty

Answer (score 0):

It's a issue with the database you don't have the table in your database for which you used the query either upload the database on the server Or run the migration .